# Using too many functions

Tags: c++, function, c++11

I'm reading a book in which a window class' constructor doesn't initialize all the implementation directly, instead it calls a function that calls another etc...

e.g.

```
window::window(T&t, X&x)
{ setup(t, x);}

void window::setup(T&t, X&x)
{
//initializing implementation details, size, title etc...
create(t, x);

void window::create(T&t, X&x)
{
//initializing the library Window
//...
}
```

Same with the destructor, callind a destroy() function instead of doing so in the destructor itself.

Is it just a matter of style or is it of any practical use?

Comment: Hard to say anything about that without seeing the book and more context.

Comment: Does window have more than 1 constructor?

Comment: ... And is placing all of the code directly in the constructor/destructor make it *very* long?

Comment: My guess is that it is a book from a time when [delegating constructors](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/5894415f-be62-4bc0-81c5-3956e82276f3/entry/introduction_to_the_c_11_feature_delegating_constructors?lang=en) did not exist.

Comment: It has more than 1 constructor, which justifies the setup() function, but why using another function and call create()?

Comment: Did they separate the functionality of creation from initialization?

Comment: Is setup public?  It may be that window can be moved around by calling setup multiple times.

Answer (score 2):

If the initialization of members is implemented as a function, that function can be re-used across multiple constructors. A public initialization function allows the default constructor to leave the object in a partially initialized state that can be initialized later. This can allow a class to be DefaultConstructible if it wasn't otherwise possible while still giving the option of full initialization with a non-default constructor.

Implementing a destroy function, and calling it in the destructor allows the user of the object to release resources managed by the object before the destruction of the object. This allows re-use of the object memory with multiple sets of resources (a minor optimization).

Comment: These days it often makes more sense to use delegating constructors (IMHO).

Answer (score 0):

It is of practical use, following the principle of [Don't Repeat Yourself (DRY)](http://wiki.c2.com/?DontRepeatYourself). You should read [Martin Fowler on Function Length](http://www.martinfowler.com/bliki/FunctionLength.html).